# Node.js Reference Error: Class is not defined

Tags: node.js

I am writing a module that exports a few functions. I created a file that calls the module but cant seem to get the file to reference my class created in the module. Im not sure what Im doing wrong. Here is the code.

```
 var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
 var inherits = require('util').inherits;  

 var employeeEmitter = function(){}
 function employeeEmitter(data){
  EventEmitter.call(this);
 }           
 inherits(employeeEmitter, EventEmitter);   

 employeeEmitter.prototype.lookupByLastName = function(data, lastName)
 {var lName = _.where(data, {lastName: lastName});
 console.log(colors.red('Lookup By Last Name: ' + (lastName)));
 console.log(colors.blue('Event lookupByLastName raised! '+ lastName));
 console.log(lName); 
 };

 employeeEmitter.prototype.lookupById=function(data, id){
 console.log(colors.red('Lookup By ID: ' +id));
 console.log(colors.blue('Event lookupById'));   
 Id = _.findWhere(data, {id: id });
 console.log(Id);
 };

 module.export = employeeEmitter;
```

This is the file I am using to call the above module

```
  var EmployeeEmitter = require('./employeeEmitter.js');
  data = [
  {id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'},
  {id:2, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith'},
  {id:3, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}
   ];

  var EmployeeEmitter = new employeeEmitter(data);
  EmployeeEmitter.on('event1', function(data) {
  }); 


  EmployeeEmitter.lookupByLastName(data, 'Smith');
  EmployeeEmitter.addEmployee(data, 'William', 'Smith');
  EmployeeEmitter.lookupByLastName(data, 'Smith');
  EmployeeEmitter.lookupById(data, 2);
```

When I call this file I get: Reference Error employeeEmitter is not defined

Comment: You have not defined variable 'employeeEmitter' in your code.  Change your first line into :   var employeeEmitter = require('./employeeEmitter.js');

Comment: module.exportS - missing an s in the original definition.

Comment: Also remove this line `var employeeEmitter = function(){}`.